# Resources for beginners - how to determine probability of user action based on certain criteria?

Tags: dataset, references

Sorry if this is similar to another question, but I'm still trying to learn data analysis and I don't know what to search for.

What I'd like to do is take some information that a potential customer enters into a web form and figure out the probability that they'll become a customer... giving our sales team an idea of which leads are most valuable. Specifically, being a travel company, there are criteria like origin and destination, date of travel vs. date they fill the form, and even how much/little they fill out the 3 subjective questions (about 100-150 characters seems ideal).

I'm not even sure what the terminology is, so if anyone can provide some direction about where I can go to learn about this, I'd be very appreciative.

Thanks!

Comment: In the jargon of web marketing, this probability is called the 'conversion rate'. Not my field, but the Wikipedia articles may give you some leads: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_rate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem can be described as "binary classification problem" with the response variable "become_customer" $\in$ {yes,no}.

As far as see, your next steps should be:

1. create a tabular dataset with one row = one visitor and columns = predictors + response variable. Predictor variables reflect the input into the forms (as described by you), meanwhile response is "yes", if the visitor became a customer, else "no".
2. learn and validate (keyword: Crossvalidation; metrics like AUC, Precision, Recall etc.) an expressive (non black-box) classification model. On suggestion is "Decision Trees", which are mainly used in the area of Direct Marketing / Performance Marketing since they can give you a description of potential customers.
3. By calibrating the output of the scores of the classification model you can additionally get an estimate of the conversion rate for each customer.

Comment: Thanks! Great info, and definitely puts me on the right path. With 2 more rep points, I'd happily give an arrow-up.

Comment: Also, I did a search for book recommendations, but I'm not sure what to look for. Books on "binary classification"?

Comment: The task classification (with special case binary classification) is part of every basic book on machine learning and data mining (my favorite: "Data Mining: Practical Machine Learning Tools and Techniques" by Witten & Frank)